# Detect iPad Air/3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I ma in trouble with detecting iPad. I have a code for detecting if its iPhone 4/4s, iPhone 5/5s or iPad mini. But I have no idea how to detect iPad air(1536 x 2048). If I use this code it returns me for iPad retina in simulator the settings I set for iPhone 5.

```
 if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
            if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) {
                if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568){
                   //iPhone5
                } else{
                    //Iphone4
                     }
        }else {
           //iPadmini


        }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed it!

```
#define iPhone4Or5oriPad ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568 ? 5 : ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480 ? 4 : 999))

    if (iPhone4Or5oriPad==4) {
                                 NSLog(@"This is 3.5 inch iPhone - iPhone 4s or below");
                             } else if (iPhone4Or5oriPad==5) {
                                 NSLog(@"This is 4 inch iPhone - iPhone 5 & above");
                             } else {
                                 NSLog(@"This is iPad");
                             }
```